# In Surv(start_time, end_time, new_death) : Stop time must be > start time, NA created

Tags: r, number-formatting, survival

I am using the package "survival" to fit a cox model with time intervals (intervals are 30 days long). I am reading the data in from an xlsx worksheet.  I keep getting the error that says my stop time must be greater than my start time. The start values are all smaller than the stop values.

I checked to make sure these are being read in as numbers which they are. I also changed them to integers which did not solve the problem. I used this code to see if any observations met this criterion:

```
a <- a1[which(a1$end_time > a1$start_time),]
```

About half the dataset meets this criterion, but when I look at the data all the start times appear to be less than the end times.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it? I am an R newbie so perhaps there is something obvious I don't know about?

```
model1<- survfit(Surv(start_time, end_time, censor) ~ exp, data=a1, weights = weight)
```

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Idck.gif)

Comment: Could you share the output of `dput(a1)` ?

Comment: if you are  intending only to use the data that meets your criteria, then your survfit should call `data=a` not `data=a1`

Comment: @rawr I am not intending to use only the data that meet a criterion, I wanted to see which data met that condition. It doesn't look like any do so I think there is some formatting a newbie like me doesn't understand. I posted a snip of the dataset

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear before and I wasn't able to edit my comment:@rawr I want the columns to have start_time < end_time (in 30-day intervals). All the values look like this is true, but about half of them meet the condition start_time > end_time. I can't see why this would be the case (all the start_time numbers *appear* to be less than the end_time numbers). Is there is some underlying formatting a newbie like me doesn't understand? I posted a snip of the dataset. Both a1 and a *look* identical.

Comment: I think the problem here is that you are not specifying the argument `type`. You should specify `type = "interval"`, I think the default here is assuming `type = "counting"` which I don't think you want. Check out the documentation for `Surv` for more info.